# Is it necessary to #include <exception>, when I seem to be able to use std::exception even when it is not included?

Tags: c++

I probably am overlooking something simple, but this boggles me: How come that this code actually compiles, at least in MS Visual Studio 2012, even when `<exception>` is not included? Is it included implicitly somehow? Is this somehow related to the IDE? Should I include it, and why?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    try 
    {
        throw std::exception("THIS HAS FAILED SPECTACULARLY");
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception occured:\n";
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`iostream` includes it internally in your implementation, but you shouldn't rely on that.  For portability better to be explicit and include the headers you explicitly use items from.

Answer (score 3):

Because its included by `iostream` (somewhere deep deep within)

```
iostream -> istream -> ostream -> ios -> xlocnum -> streambuf -> xiosbase -> system_error -> exception
```

But this is implementation dependent (above: vc runtime)

Comment: What is `xlocnum` and `ziosbase`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 As far as I can tell from the comments inside the headerfiles, `xlocnum` is related to `locale` and contains e.g the `numpunct` facet. `xiosbase` is related to `ios` and contains definitions of various ios flags aswell as the definition of `ios_base`